# How to visualize a torch_geometric graph in Python?

Tags: charts, pytorch, draw

Let's consider as an example that I have the following adjacence matrix in coordinate format:

```
> edge_index.numpy() = array([[    0,     1,     0,   3,   2],
                              [    1,     0,     3,   2,   1]], dtype=int64)
```

which means that the node 0 is linked toward the node 1, and vice-versa, the node 0 is linked to 3 etc.

How to draw this graph as in networkx with `nx.draw()`?

Comment: see this too: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-geometric/44994

Answer (score 18):

```py
import networkx as nx

edge_index = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 1, 2],
                           [1, 0, 2, 1]], dtype=torch.long)
x = torch.tensor([[-1], [0], [1]], dtype=torch.float)

data = torch_geometric.data.Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index)
g = torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx(data, to_undirected=True)
nx.draw(g)
```

Comment: How to add node ID?